# Laravel union few tables and sort the result by a column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 separate select queries, each results in a table with the same columns, like id and created_at.
I want to union then, order by created_at and get the most recent created_at for each id. So I'll also need to use group by.

The example from documentation results in `(select ..) union (select ...)`, but I cannot figure out how to do something like

```
DB::select(DB::raw(id, MAX(created_at))
->from($query1->union($query2)->union($query3)->union($query4)))
->groupBy('id')
->orderBy('created_at');
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :)

```
$query1 = DB::table('table1')->where(....);
$query2 = DB::table('table2')->where(....);
$query3 = DB::table('table3')->where(....);
$query4 = DB::table('table4')->where(....);
$query5 = DB::table('table5')->where(....);

$data = DB::select(DB::raw('id, MAX(created_at) as max_created_at')
          ->union($query1)->union($query2)->union($query3)->union($query4)->union($query5)
          ->orderBy('max_created_at')
          ->groupBy('id')
          ->get();
```

Let me know if you face any issues :)

Comment: It results in a different query. I want to "select * from (unions...) group by id" and I get (select * from table group by id) union (...)

Comment: @Victor Check now? Edited my answer

Comment: it seem $data missing a ) and when i put this after all unions i'll get undefined union method error!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fromSub()` method to add your unioned queries as a sub query and perform your groupBy and other aggregations on that result

```
$union_query = $query1->union($query2)->union($query3);
$results = DB::query()
                ->fromSub($union_query, 'union_query')
                ->select('id', DB::raw('MAX(created_at) as most_recent'))
                ->groupBy('id')
                ->orderBy('most_recent', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Ref: Answer by PatBriPerso [in this laracasts discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-groupby-after-union)

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following:

- **Merge all your queries to a collection**

$result = $query1->merge($query2)->merge($query3)->merge($query4);

- **Add the methods that you need to the collection**

$filtered = $collection->groupBy('id')->sortBy('created_at');

Comment: In case there are a lot of rows in DB there will be a memory issue. Like imagine there are 100k rows and I'll create collection of 100k items